# Azure compatible client tools

Tags: azure-sql-database

I'm building a DB for someone as a favor and whilst I'm perfectly OK to create a DB in Azure SQL for them and do the requisite TSQL coding they require I do also need to give them a client based way to access the data that involves no non-SQL coding from me.

Ideally this would be a light weight alternative to SSMS that is compatibile with Azure. That way I can give them a series of scripts and paramtised SPs to run. Can someone recommend something that works please?

Thanks for reading

Edit: Put on hold for "will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion" but this came after the question had been answered and had not caused such.

Comment: Have a look at LINQPad -- http://www.linqpad.net/ SQL Azure is supported as well.

Comment: Looks good Kin.. feel free to submit it as an answer

Comment: Squirrel client looks like it could be a winner too, just in case anyone else reads this question ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/). SQL Azure is supported as well.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps SQL Azure Database Manager? Requires a browser, internet connection, and Silverlight. http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2295/getting-started-with-the-sql-azure-database-manager/